# Интервал в СИ отрабатывает иначе чем в других языках

Tags: python, c

```
int x = 141;
if (75 > x < 61)
    printf("1");
else
    printf("2");
```

Данный код выдает 1 в ответе
Однако в Питоне такой же код выдаст ответ 2
Понятно, что правильная запись интервала в СИ иная, но что происходит под капотом у СИ в данном случае, как он трактует данное условие?

Задание взято из задачника

Comment: выдает 1 и 2 для какого х?

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл дописать.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: (предположение) сначала оценивается 75 > x, это false, потом оценивается false < 61, при этом false приводится к 0. Получается true

Comment: @Эникейщик, а как в Си 0 трактуется как true, если, насколько помню, true - это алиас для 1, а false - для 0?

Comment: @SergeyK. где написано, что 0 трактуется как true?

Comment: 0 (это результат сравнения `75 >  x`) меньше  чем 61

Comment: Автор вопроса - в этом блоке if (75 > x < 61) будет результат true можно записать как один 1 правильно вроде бы, но в этом блоке else почему 2?

Answer (score 10):

Такие выражения, в которых в одной строке несколько знаков операций например,

```
2*3 + 4*5
```

разбираются с учетом ассоциативности (слева направо или справа налево) операторов и их приоритета (умножение вычисляется раньше, чем сложение и т.п.)

Поэтому, так как операторы "больше" и "меньше" имеют одинаковый приоритет и левоассоциативны, выражение

```
75 > x < 61
```

вычисляется по правилам языка следующим образом: сначала вычисляется результат сравнения `75 > x`, а затем полученный результат (`true` или `false`, которые приводятся к 1 и 0) сравнивается с 61

```
(75 > x) < 61
```

что, конечно же, всегда истинно, каким бы ни было значение `x`. То, что вы хотите (лежит ли `x` в диапазоне от 61 до 75, не включая крайние значения), вычисляется в С так:

```
x > 61 && x < 75
```